# interpretation of treatment effect from linear mix model when Y is log-transformed in longitudinal analysis

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model

In a clinical study, 100 patients are evenly divided into two treatment group, trtA and trtB. For each patient, a biomarker is measured at 5 different visit timepoints. Y is the measured biomarker level.

I'm using linear mix model to evaluate treatment effect along the time course. 
I can build two models with `Y` or `log(Y)` as below.

```
# model1
Y = lmer(Y~Visit+treatment+(1|subject)), data=data )
# model2 (log-transformed Y)
log(Y) = lmer(Y~Visit+treatment+(1|subject), data=data)
```

My question is: say treatment effect is significant, how should I interpret model result (significance of treatment effect),  using original Y vs. log-transformed Y? (model1 vs model2). I feel somehow they should be different....

```
There is a statistically significant difference between 
trtA and trtB along the time course...?
```

One additional question: 
How should I interpret model result, when Visit is treated as factor variable vs continuous variable (number of days), say the treatment term is significant.

Thanks a lot in advance.